# How to set custom cell property values with VBA in Visio?

Tags: vba, visio

I have a drawing with hundreds of shapes, and they all have the same data set applied to them.  In this case let's say I want to change the value in row "Prop.Row_5" to 0001 for every shape.

Currently I have:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page, vsoShape As Visio.Shape
    Dim vsoStrng As String

    For Each vsoPage In ThisDocument.Pages
        For Each vsoShape In vsoPage.Shapes
            vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, 4, visCustPropsValue).FormulaU = "0001"

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

This is one of several different methods I have tried, nothing seems to work.  Can somebody clear this up for me?

Comment: Where are you running the code from?  Are you targeting a particular document, as 'ThisDocument' will refer to the document that's hosting the code.  Have you checked that you're actually hitting that CellSRC line?  Add a breakpoint (click in the left margin)...when you hit the breakpoint, is the shape reference the one you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if the property is a number, or you can put it without commas,

```
Dim vsoPage As Page
Dim vsoShape As Shape

For Each vsoPage In ThisDocument.Pages
    For Each vsoShape In vsoPage.Shapes
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intRowNum, _
            visCustPropsValue).FormulaU = 1
    Next
Next
```

But, if the property is a string, you must use three commas, like

```
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intRowNum, _ 
            visCustPropsValue).FormulaU = """0001"""
```

This is because the formula itself is a string which evaluates to a string only if it contains the "" characters inside. Otherwise, if looks for a variable, function or cell named as the string you entered.

Hope this helps you.

Regards,